# How to call javascript method from ClientTemplate in Kendo grid?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

Is it possible to put in the ClientTemplate of Kendo grid a javascript statement?
I would like to calculate some data on the client and then to put the result in the row.

I tried this:

```
 columns.Bound("ExecutionStartDateTime").Title("SummaryLine").Width("20%").ClientTemplate("<script> scheduleForm.generateSummary(#= ExecutionStartDateTime #, 2); </script>");
```

However, it gave no effect.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can, with template literal syntax:

```
<script>
    function someFuntion(date) {
        var result = "";
        // Do whatever you need here (make ajax call etc..) and return result as html string
        return result;
    }
</script>
```

And bound your column as:

```
columns.Bound("ExecutionStartDateTime").Title("SummaryLine").Width("20%")
    .ClientTemplate("#=someFuntion(ExecutionStartDateTime)#");   
// you can even pass 'data' implicit template parameter and extract ExecutionStartDateTime from there
```

You can even write inline javascript simply using # if(...){# ... #}# syntax. [This](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/faq#how-do-i-use-a-javascript-function-in-a-column-client-template?) faq will help you.